# Android Bluetooth multiple connection issue?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, insecure-connection

I am new in Android, I am working on a project where I have to connect My device with all devices  which can be found in by **`startDiscovery()`** call Using Bluetooth. I have gone through with **`bluetooth chat sample`**, but issue is that for make connection I need to click on item of search-devices in the list, but I want to send data object on all the devices in the list.. is that possible with **`listenUsingInsecureComm..`**,? but I am not getting the way how to pair with other search devices without permission (that the receiving device dont need to click Yes for pairing)?

I also visited related question here but can't get my solution.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana for edition in the question,

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly but according to `Bluetooth chat` code for making a more connection you have to make array of `BluetoothDevice` and also you have to manage separate threads for all connections. 
means you have to make array of threads for reading and writing data from remote devices and each thread will associated with only one device means for device 1 there is a thread1 and for device 2 there is a thread 2 and so on.

Comment: Array of Threads for reading and writing, seems acceptable, would you examples few lines of statements, for me, as i am at beginner level here. Thanks in Advance.