# How can we set up multiple classic Bluetooth connections simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rfcomm

I am currently working on an application that requires the use of classic Bluetooth to transfer data between smartphones by making multiple connections. What do I mean by multiple connections? A device can maintain a Bluetooth connection with at least 2 devices at the same time and more if possible.
I read in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) dedicated to setting up a connection through RFCOMM channels that it is possible to set up multiple connections and use multiple channels. Everything suggests that multiple connections are possible. The problem is that at no point does the documentation indicate how this can be done: the [example provided by Android](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat) on the classic Bluetooth only allows one connection at a time.
Therefore, I wonder:

> Should another UUID be set up using a different socket?
> Can a device connect using a socket already in use?
> How many simultaneous connections can be set up?

Comment: Try looking at [Android Bluetooth API connect to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468658/android-bluetooth-api-connect-to-multiple-devices).